# Get json value with Alamofire

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I got the value of "16" from my key"Value" in tax_ncurrency. I'm using Alamofire to handle the json, but but i cant assign it to my label: productTax

```
    ["data": (
        {
        "tax_n_currency" =         {
            Value = 16;
            Variable = Tax;
        };
    },
        {
        "tax_n_currency" =         {
            Value = USD;
            Variable = Currency;
        };
    }
)]
```

my request .

```
     Alamofire.request(.GET, url!, parameters: ["accesskey":223344666]).responseJSON { (request, response, result) in

         let json = result.value as! [String:AnyObject]
        print(json)
        let data = json["data"] as! [AnyObject]
        //print(mm)

        let taxnCurrency = data[0]["tax_n_currency"] as! NSDictionary
        print(taxnCurrency)

        if let tax = taxnCurrency["Value"]?.intValue{
            self.productTax.text = "\(tax) %"
            print(tax)
        }
    }
```

Comment: `let tax = json["Value"]?.intValue` => `let tax = taxnCurrency["Value"]?.intValue`?

Comment: i already noticed a made that mistake, but it says too uwrap it with "!" and when i try it says again (so basically 2 times teh unwrap)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if let tax = data["data"] as? [AnyObject],
        tax_n_currency = tax["tax_n_currency"] as? [String:AnyObject],
        value = tax_n_currency["Value"] as? Int {
    print(value)
}
```

Comment: what to replace with what ?

Comment: if let tax = json["Value"]?.intValue.. That line,

Comment: @EricD, could you tell me if I've done this right? Can I do this? Or is it inappropriate to ask someone help like this?

Comment: @Dershowitz123 If you want to discuss with an user it's better to ask them to join you in a chatroom (but I think you don't have enough rep yet for that). As a personal choice, I usually ignore requests in comments if it's not posted on my answers, but there can be exceptions - they're rare, though. ;)

Comment: I don't have enough rep @EricD. Alternatives?? :(

Answer (score 0):

I like to work with the `if` statement to check if the variable is really set, you can use prints to check if is get in the `if` statement. If this not work, provide more information about the JSON.
EDIT: Change the first conditional to a array of Dict

```
 Alamofire.request(.GET, url!, parameters: ["accesskey":223344666]).responseJSON { (request, response, result) in
        var taxnCurrency: Integer!
        let json = result.value as! [String:AnyObject]
        let data = json["data"] as! [[String:AnyObjecy]]

        if let dict = json[0]["tax_n_currency"] {
                      if let tax = dict["Value"] as! Integer {
                          taxnCurrency = tax
                      }
                   }
```

Comment: i dont have any more infos about json, and the code doesnt work first: i have to make the casting Optional[String:AnyObject],  and in `if let tax= data["tax_n_xurrency"] as! ... it says has no subscript members

Comment: print(result.value) and you can check the struct of the json. Could you do this and edit in your question?

Comment: So after the first if, could print(json) and paste here?

Comment: I edited my answer, I checked with my json here and I believe that you have a Array of NSDict.

Comment: can you edit your answer with my code included , so i can see it all